# How can I retrieve the memory address of a 64-bit pointer?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory

I'm developing a trainer for a flash game which will support 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

I trying to return the memory address of a pointer so that I can use the memory address to change the value. I am able to do this perfectly fine in the 32-bit version. But, in the 64-bit version it returns an incorrect memory address.

The trainer currently only supports Google Chrome. If you're using the 32-bit trainer, Chrome needs to be 32-bit. If you're using the 64-bit trainer, Chrome needs to be 64-bit.

**This is the 32-bit pointer's information from Cheat Engine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheatTable>
  <CheatEntries>
    <CheatEntry>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Description>"pointerscan result"</Description>
      <LastState Value="10000" RealAddress="071DCAA8"/>
      <VariableType>4 Bytes</VariableType>
      <Address>"pepflashplayer.dll"+01035A80</Address>
      <Offsets>
        <Offset>28</Offset>
        <Offset>28</Offset>
        <Offset>464</Offset>
        <Offset>B8</Offset>
        <Offset>80</Offset>
      </Offsets>
    </CheatEntry>
  </CheatEntries>
</CheatTable>
```

**The code below will successfully retrieve the memory address of the 32-bit pointer:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Trainer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress, [Out] byte[] buffer, int size,
            out IntPtr bytesRead);

        public static int ReadInt32(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4];
            IntPtr bytesRead;
            ReadProcessMemory(process, baseAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesRead);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        }

        private static ProcessModule GetProcessModule(Process process, string moduleName)
        {
            foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
            {
                if (module.ModuleName == moduleName)
                {
                    return module;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static int GetRealAddress(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress, int[] offsets)
        {
            var address = baseAddress.ToInt32();
            foreach (var offset in offsets)
            {
                address = ReadInt32(process, (IntPtr)address) + offset;
            }
            return address;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);

            // Get the first Chrome process that contains a module named "pepflashplayer.dll".
            var chromeProcess =
                Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                        process =>
                            process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>()
                                .Any(module => module.ModuleName == "pepflashplayer.dll"));

            if (chromeProcess != null)
            {
                var flashPlayerModule = GetProcessModule(chromeProcess, "pepflashplayer.dll");
                var baseAddress = flashPlayerModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + 0x01035A80;
                var offsets = new[] { 0x80, 0xB8, 0x464, 0x28, 0x28 };

                var realAddress = GetRealAddress(chromeProcess.Handle, (IntPtr)baseAddress, offsets);
                Console.WriteLine(realAddress.ToString("X"));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> False
>
> 83CAAA8

**This is the 64-bit pointer's information from Cheat Engine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheatTable>
  <CheatEntries>
    <CheatEntry>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Description>"pointerscan result"</Description>
      <LastState Value="10000" RealAddress="2A0C3492B38"/>
      <VariableType>4 Bytes</VariableType>
      <Address>"pepflashplayer.dll"+01CB16E8</Address>
      <Offsets>
        <Offset>48</Offset>
        <Offset>3D8</Offset>
        <Offset>370</Offset>
        <Offset>7A8</Offset>
        <Offset>360</Offset>
      </Offsets>
    </CheatEntry>
  </CheatEntries>
</CheatTable>
```

**The code below is my attempt to retrieve the memory address of the 64-bit pointer:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Trainer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress, [Out] byte[] buffer, int size,
            out IntPtr bytesRead);

        public static long ReadInt64(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8];
            IntPtr bytesRead;
            ReadProcessMemory(process, baseAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesRead);
            return BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
        }

        private static ProcessModule GetProcessModule(Process process, string moduleName)
        {
            foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
            {
                if (module.ModuleName == moduleName)
                {
                    return module;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static long GetRealAddress(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseAddress, int[] offsets)
        {
            var address = baseAddress.ToInt64();
            foreach (var offset in offsets)
            {
                address = ReadInt64(process, (IntPtr)address) + offset;
            }
            return address;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);

            // Get the first Chrome process that contains a module named "pepflashplayer.dll".
            var chromeProcess =
                Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                        process =>
                            process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>()
                                .Any(module => module.ModuleName == "pepflashplayer.dll"));

            if (chromeProcess != null)
            {
                var flashPlayerModule = GetProcessModule(chromeProcess, "pepflashplayer.dll");
                var baseAddress = flashPlayerModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + 0x01CB16E8;
                var offsets = new[] { 0x360, 0x7A8, 0x370, 0x3D8, 0x48 };

                var realAddress = GetRealAddress(chromeProcess.Handle, (IntPtr)baseAddress, offsets);
                Console.WriteLine(realAddress.ToString("X"));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> True
>
> 48

How can I retrieve the memory address of a 64-bit pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you allocate 8 bytes:

```
var buffer = new byte[8];
IntPtr bytesRead;
```

and here you read **just 4**:

```
ReadProcessMemory(process, baseAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesRead);
```